# How to add Expires headers to Nginx?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, virtualhost, http-headers

I have a Ubuntu server 18.04 with Drupal 8 and I do not master the Nginx server at all.

I just migrated my old Apache server to a new Nginx server. In my htaccess file at the root of my site, I had Expires headers :

```
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault A1209600

      <FilesMatch \.php$>
        ExpiresActive Off
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

How to add this my Nginx configuration ?

Comment: I have a tutorial that is likely to help [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/).

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/expires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple. From your supplied Apache config, it seems you don't want to add it to .php files, but do want to use it everywhere else. Put the following in your server context:

```
expires 1209600s;
```

Then, add:

```
expires off;
```

To your `location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php'` block. You do not need to add this to any of your other location blocks that operate on php, where you have a `deny` directive, a `rewrite` directive or a `try_files` directive, as the `deny` won't add the header, and the `try_files` and `rewrite` blocks is not the final location block matched, as an internal redirect will result from those, causing location matching to be re-started after.

Refer to the [Nginx expires](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) documentation.